# Android layout multiple screen sizes and densities

Tags: android, layout

I have the following layout. I have images in the ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, and xhdpi appropriate folders. I don't understand why the layout does not scale to the appropriate size. I added the ScrollView so at least you can scroll to see the entire layout, but this is not the desired effect. I would like all content to be visible at all sizes and densities without scrolling. I have read the Android docs on supporting multiple sizes and densities, but I don't understand where to go from here. I am using the "adb shell am display-density" and "adb shell am display-size" commands to emulate different devices on my Nexus 10. Thanks in advance.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<RelativeLayout 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/bg" >

<View
  android:id="@+id/viewSpacer0"
  android:layout_width="1dp"
  android:layout_height="7dip"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<LinearLayout
  android:id="@+id/linearLayoutLine1"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_below="@+id/viewSpacer0" >

<ImageView
  android:id="@+id/imageLogo"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:scaleType="fitCenter"
  android:src="@drawable/logo_large" />

<View
  android:id="@+id/viewSpacer1"
  android:layout_width="20dp"
  android:layout_height="1dip" />

<ImageView
  android:id="@+id/imageView50Best"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:adjustViewBounds="true"
  android:src="@drawable/fifty_best_logo" />

</LinearLayout>

<View
  android:id="@+id/viewSpacer2"
  android:layout_width="1dp"
  android:layout_height="10dip"
  android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayoutLine1"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TableLayout
  android:id="@+id/tableLayoutHeader"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_below="@+id/viewSpacer2"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
  android:background="@color/transparent" >

<TableRow
  android:id="@+id/tableRowPhoneNumberLabels"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:gravity="center" >

<TextView
  android:id="@+id/textViewHospital"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="Hospital"
  android:textSize="20sp"
  android:textColor="@color/white" />

<View
  android:id="@+id/viewSpacerBetweenLabels"
  android:layout_width="15dp"
  android:layout_height="1dip"
  android:layout_below="@+id/tableLayoutHeader"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
  android:id="@+id/textViewEmergencyRoom"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="Emergency Room"
  android:textSize="20sp"
  android:textColor="@color/white" />

</TableRow>

<TableRow
  android:id="@+id/tableRowPhoneNumbers"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:gravity="center" >

<TextView
  android:id="@+id/textViewHospitalSwitchboard"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="(xxx) xxx-xxxx"
  android:textSize="20sp"
  android:textColor="@color/white" />

<View
  android:id="@+id/viewSpacerBetweenPhoneNumbers"
  android:layout_width="15dp"
  android:layout_height="1dip"
  android:layout_below="@+id/tableLayoutHeader"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
  android:id="@+id/textViewEmergencyPhone"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="(xxx) xxx-xxxx"
  android:textSize="20sp"
  android:textColor="@color/white" />

</TableRow>

</TableLayout>

<View
  android:id="@+id/viewSpacer3"
  android:layout_width="1dp"
  android:layout_height="15dip"
  android:layout_below="@+id/tableLayoutHeader"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TableLayout
  android:id="@+id/tableLayoutMenu"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_below="@+id/viewSpacer3"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
  android:background="@color/transparent" >

<TableRow
  android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:gravity="center" >

<ImageButton
  android:id="@+id/imageDrSearch"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@color/transparent"
  android:padding="@dimen/padding_xsmall"
  android:src="@drawable/icon_dr_search" />

<ImageButton
  android:id="@+id/imageLocations"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@color/transparent"
  android:padding="@dimen/padding_xsmall"
  android:src="@drawable/icon_locations" />

</TableRow>

<TableRow
  android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:gravity="center" >

<ImageButton
  android:id="@+id/imageSendCard"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@color/transparent"
  android:padding="@dimen/padding_xsmall"
  android:src="@drawable/icon_send_card" />

<ImageButton
  android:id="@+id/imageServices"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@color/transparent"
  android:padding="@dimen/padding_xsmall"
  android:src="@drawable/icon_services" />

</TableRow>

<TableRow
  android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:gravity="center" >

<ImageButton
  android:id="@+id/ImageHealthEncyclopedia"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@color/transparent"
  android:padding="@dimen/padding_xsmall"
  android:src="@drawable/icon_health_encyclopedia" />

<ImageButton
  android:id="@+id/imageClassesEvents"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@color/transparent"
  android:padding="@dimen/padding_xsmall"
  android:src="@drawable/icon_events_classes" />

</TableRow>

<TableRow
  android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:gravity="center" >

<ImageButton
  android:id="@+id/imageCareers"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@color/transparent"
  android:padding="@dimen/padding_xsmall"
  android:src="@drawable/icon_careers" />

<ImageButton
  android:id="@+id/imageNewsroom"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@color/transparent"
  android:padding="@dimen/padding_xsmall"
  android:src="@drawable/icon_newsroom" />

</TableRow>

</TableLayout>

<View
  android:id="@+id/viewSpacer4"
  android:layout_width="1dp"
  android:layout_height="5dip"
  android:layout_below="@+id/tableLayoutMenu"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<LinearLayout
  android:id="@+id/linearLayoutLine3"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
  android:layout_below="@+id/viewSpacer4"
  android:background="@color/lightgrey" >

<ImageButton
  android:id="@+id/imageViewWebsite"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@color/transparent"
  android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium"
  android:src="@drawable/www_small" />

<ImageButton
  android:id="@+id/imageViewFacebook"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@color/transparent"
  android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium"
  android:src="@drawable/facebook_small" />

<ImageButton
  android:id="@+id/imageViewTwitter"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@color/transparent"
  android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium"
  android:src="@drawable/twitter_small" />

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Updated after GLee's suggestions:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg" >

<View
  android:id="@+id/viewSpacer0"
  android:layout_width="1dp"
  android:layout_height="7dip"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<LinearLayout
  android:id="@+id/linearLayoutLine1"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_below="@+id/viewSpacer0" >

<ImageView
  android:id="@+id/imageLogo"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_weight="2"
  android:scaleType="center"
  android:src="@drawable/logo_large" />

<View
  android:id="@+id/viewSpacer1"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:layout_width="20dp"
  android:layout_height="1dip" />

<ImageView
  android:id="@+id/imageView50Best"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_weight="2"
  android:adjustViewBounds="true"
  android:src="@drawable/fifty_best_logo" />

</LinearLayout>

<TableLayout
  android:id="@+id/tableLayoutHeader"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayoutLine1"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
  android:background="@color/transparent" >

<TableRow
  android:id="@+id/tableRowPhoneNumberLabels"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:gravity="center" >

<TextView
  android:id="@+id/textViewHospital"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="Hospital"
  android:layout_weight="2"
  android:textSize="20sp"
  android:textColor="@color/white" />

<View
  android:id="@+id/viewSpacerBetweenLabels"
  android:layout_width="15dp"
  android:layout_height="1dip"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:layout_below="@+id/tableLayoutHeader" />

<TextView
  android:id="@+id/textViewEmergencyRoom"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="Emergency Room"
  android:layout_weight="2"
  android:textSize="20sp"
  android:textColor="@color/white" />

</TableRow>

<TableRow
  android:id="@+id/tableRowPhoneNumbers"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:gravity="center" >

<TextView
  android:id="@+id/textViewHospitalSwitchboard"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="(xxx) xxx-xxxx"
  android:textSize="20sp"
  android:layout_weight="2"
  android:textColor="@color/white" />

<View
  android:id="@+id/viewSpacerBetweenPhoneNumbers"
  android:layout_width="15dp"
  android:layout_height="1dip"
  android:layout_below="@+id/tableLayoutHeader"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
  android:id="@+id/textViewEmergencyPhone"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="(xxx) xxx-xxxx"
  android:textSize="20sp"
  android:layout_weight="2"
  android:textColor="@color/white" />

</TableRow>

</TableLayout>

<View
  android:id="@+id/viewSpacer3"
  android:layout_width="1dp"
  android:layout_height="15dip"
  android:layout_below="@+id/tableLayoutHeader"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TableLayout
  android:id="@+id/tableLayoutMenu"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_below="@+id/viewSpacer3"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
  android:background="@color/transparent" >

<TableRow
  android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:gravity="center" >

<ImageButton
  android:id="@+id/imageDrSearch"
  android:background="@color/transparent"
  android:padding="@dimen/padding_xsmall"
  android:scaleType="center"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:src="@drawable/icon_dr_search" />

<ImageButton
  android:id="@+id/imageLocations"
  android:background="@color/transparent"
  android:padding="@dimen/padding_xsmall"
  android:scaleType="center"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:src="@drawable/icon_locations" />

</TableRow>

<TableRow
  android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:gravity="center" >

<ImageButton
  android:id="@+id/imageSendCard"
  android:background="@color/transparent"
  android:padding="@dimen/padding_xsmall"
  android:scaleType="center"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:src="@drawable/icon_send_card" />

<ImageButton
  android:id="@+id/imageServices"
  android:background="@color/transparent"
  android:padding="@dimen/padding_xsmall"
  android:scaleType="center"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:src="@drawable/icon_services" />

</TableRow>

<TableRow
  android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:gravity="center" >

<ImageButton
  android:id="@+id/ImageHealthEncyclopedia"
  android:background="@color/transparent"
  android:padding="@dimen/padding_xsmall"
  android:scaleType="center"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:src="@drawable/icon_health_encyclopedia" />

<ImageButton
  android:id="@+id/imageClassesEvents"
  android:background="@color/transparent"
  android:padding="@dimen/padding_xsmall"
  android:scaleType="center"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:src="@drawable/icon_events_classes" />

</TableRow>

<TableRow
  android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:gravity="center" >

<ImageButton
  android:id="@+id/imageCareers"
  android:background="@color/transparent"
  android:padding="@dimen/padding_xsmall"
  android:scaleType="center"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:src="@drawable/icon_careers" />

<ImageButton
  android:id="@+id/imageNewsroom"
  android:background="@color/transparent"
  android:padding="@dimen/padding_xsmall"
  android:scaleType="center"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:src="@drawable/icon_newsroom" />

</TableRow>

</TableLayout>

<View
  android:id="@+id/viewSpacer4"
  android:layout_width="1dp"
  android:layout_height="5dip"
  android:layout_below="@+id/tableLayoutMenu"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<LinearLayout
  android:id="@+id/linearLayoutLine3"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
  android:layout_below="@+id/viewSpacer4"
  android:background="@color/lightgrey" >

<ImageButton
  android:id="@+id/imageViewWebsite"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@color/transparent"
  android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium"
  android:layout_weight="5"
  android:src="@drawable/www_small" />

<ImageButton
  android:id="@+id/imageViewFacebook"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@color/transparent"
  android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium"
  android:layout_weight="5"
  android:src="@drawable/facebook_small" />

<ImageButton
  android:id="@+id/imageViewTwitter"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@color/transparent"
  android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium"
  android:layout_weight="5"
  android:src="@drawable/twitter_small" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Maybe the img's on your resources/drawable-xxx isn't right scaled :/, I also found this a problem in one of my projects, today I'm testing this photoshop plugin (http://www.cutandslice.me/) to help-me with the resource size problems

Comment: You might also want to check that the correct screen size and DPI values are being returned during runtime in case your adb commands are being ignored.

Comment: @TheIT - Thanks for the comment. How do I do this? The screen size is changing after I run the adb commands.

Answer (score 1):

Different resources in the *dpi folders only account for screen density, not screen size.  Your image resources will still have some intrinsic size: they may be too big or too small for the space that you'd like them to fit in depending on the screen size.  There are options to provide resources based  on screen size (small, normal, large, xlarge), but these folders only divide screens into buckets.  Each bucket will still have different screen sizes, they will just be closer together.  Therefore, it is impossible to provide exactly the right resource size for every screen.  Instead, you need to tell your layout to scale things appropriately.  For instance, right now, with `android:layout_height="wrap_content",` you are telling your top level RelativeLayout that you'd like it to be as long as it needs to be, even if it extends offscreen.  Instead you should delete the scroll view and use`android:layout_height="match_parent"` to pin it to the size of your screen.  Inside of your LinearLayouts, use `android:layout_weight` to define which objects take up empty space.  On ImageViews, use `android:scaleType` to define how your image should scale.

Comment: Thanks so much for your advice. I've been playing with the layout. See the post above for my changes. It has improved a bit, but I'm still far off. Any other suggestions?

Comment: What is wrong with it?  You might want to change your relative layout to a linear layout, and use weights for all of its children as well.  You also might just have too much stuff for some smaller screens.

Comment: Small and normal screens (defined on http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html as "Table 3") have the bottom and sides cut off. The bottom is cut off on some of the large screen sizes. How do I make the layout completely visible on all sizes?

Comment: Some of your image views are probably too big when using the higher res images since you still have wrap_content set for your imageviews and their enclosing layouts.  Try using smaller images.  You could also try making your top layout a linear layout, and then setting the child linear layouts to match_parent with a layout_weight.  Lastly, try starting with just your top level layout and adding things one at a time.  That way you know what is screwing you up.